# Align two block in a div

Tags: css, html, block

I have create this block:
[image: first image]

and I would have two parts in this block, like this:
[image: second image]

here is my block:

```
<div id="content_sc" > 
        <img src='images/paypal-donate.jpg'> 
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#content_sc {
top: 15px;
background: #fff;
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

I tried a lot of things, but without achieving what I wanted to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/VALCw/

Just a case of floating your two elements left and putting overflow on the container really.